# Count not working properly when use equal operator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The `$eq` operator is not working properly when use count().

```
> db.WebUser.find()
{ "_id" : 6, "Country" : "In", "DOJ" : ISODate("2016-12-31T18:30:00Z") }
{ "_id" : 7, "Country" : "In", "DOJ" : ISODate(**"2017-01-04T**18:30:00Z") }
> db.WebUser.count( { DOJ: { $eq: new Date('**01/01/2017'**) } } )
1
>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The format in which you are specifying date is worng your date expression will evaluate to:

```
d = new Date('01/01/2017')
ISODate("2016-12-31T18:30:00Z")
```

You can try that in monogo shell.

The correct format is

```
db.WebUser.count( { DOJ: { $eq: new Date('2017-01-01') } } )
0
```

Comment: Your date in parameter is `ISODate("2017-01-04T00:00:00Z")` but in the document is `ISODate("2017-01-04T18:30:00Z")`. Consider the time too. If you need to query on date use [aggregation date operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/).